# What trophies can be viewed on each PlayStation platform?

Tags: achievements, ps3, ps4, ps-vita, ps5

Recently, I was looking through my trophy list on my PS4, and noticed that my PS5 trophies weren't listed, even though older systems' trophies like PS3 and PSVita were. This made me curious - what trophy lists are supported on which PlayStation platforms?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up checking all of my systems' trophy lists and making a table. Note that my.playstation.com used to allow trophy lists to be viewed from a browser, but [as of June 2021](https://www.glitched.online/sony-shutting-down-a-range-of-my-playstation-web-features/), the PlayStation mobile app is the only officially supported way to do this outside of a console.

|  | PS3 | PS Vita | PS4 | PS5 | PS mobile app |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PS3 trophies | ✅ | ✅ * | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ |
| PS4 trophies | ✅ * | ✅ * | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ |
| PS Vita trophies | ✅ * | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ |
| PS5 trophies | ❌ | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ |

*only shows trophies for platform when in Online Mode